# How to find long running queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

We are using SSAS and MOLAP. In SQL land, I know ways to query to get the longest running queries (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941763/301816)). It would be nice if we could do the same for our cube, get a list of long running MDX queries. Is this possible and what would this query look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server Profiler to monitor SSAS performance. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174779.aspx) you can e.g. *Monitor the performance of an instance of Analysis Services* and *Identify MDX statements that run slowly*.

Here is some additional resources:

- [Introduction to Using Profiler with SSAS 2008](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/adamjorgensen/ssas/463/introduction-to-using-profiler-with-ssas-2008)
- [My Quick Guide to SSAS Query Tuning Part One](https://thomasivarssonmalmo.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/my-quick-guide-to-ssas-query-tuning-part-one/)