# Get the SQL statement that invoked the CLR function

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sqlclr

Is it possible from with in a CLR function that is being executed by SQL to determine the SQL statement that invoked the CLR function in the first place. If there is no direct way, what about an indirect way like getting some kind of handle identifier and going back and querying SQL or it's logs for that info?

Example:

SQL executes:

```
select * from genericTable1 join genericCLRfunction() f on genericTable1.col = f.col;
```

and within the CLR invoked by the SQL statement calling genericCLRfunction() I would like to end up with a string equal to:

"select * from genericTable1 join genericCLRfunction() f on genericTable1.col = f.col;"

Comment: You could manually pass the whole sql as a string parameter to the CLR function, although that would be a big pain to maintain if your CLR function was called by many different SQL statements.

Comment: I have this need because I do not have the ability to update all of the SQL statements, some are hard coded in 3rd party software but I need to change the behavior of my function based on the context in which it was used.

Comment: 3rd party software has SQL which calls your SQLCLR function, but you don't have the ability to change how that 3rd party calls your function?

Comment: The third party software just takes a table name, it doesn't really know it is a CLR function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually try this right now, but here is a possibility.  You can get the session id in your CLR like so...

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true;"))
{
   cn.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@SPID", cn);
   int spid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
   cn.Close();
}
```

Then, try to use the query shown in the accepted answer for this SO question...

[List the queries running on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941763/list-the-queries-running-on-sql-server)

Comment: "SELECT  * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)

Comment: I meant: I first tried using "SELECT sqlText.text, req.session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqlText WHERE req.session_id = @@SPID" combining your first suggestion and the information from the link you provided but then half the time the result ended up being "SELECT sqlText.text, req.session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqlText WHERE req.session_id = @@SPID". So I ended up making sure the SELECT statement ran on a different connection and made the @@SPID get passed into the table function.