# Sql Server 2008 Update query is taking so much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table name `Companies` with `372370` records.

And there is only one row which has `CustomerNo = 'YP20324'`.

I an running following query and its taking so much time I waited 5 minutes and it was still running. I couldn't figure out where is the problem.

```
UPDATE Companies SET UserDefined3 = 'Unzustellbar 13.08.2012' WHERE CustomerNo = 'YP20324'
```

Comment: what about _indexes_ ??

Comment: "372370 records. " - that's a very small number....

Comment: Check the locks on the table. Try executing a `SELECT` with the same `WHERE` clause and see how much time it takes.

Comment: it takes less than a second when I execute SELECT with the same WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have triggers on update on that table?
Do you have a cascade foreign key based on that column?

Are you sure of the performance of your server? try to take a look of the memory, cpu first when you execute the query (for example on a 386 with 640mb i could understand it's slow :p)

And for the locks, you can right click the database and on the report you can see the blocking transactions. Sometimes it helps for concurrent access.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an index on the field you are using in your `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_CompaniesCustomerNo ON Companies(CustomerNo);
```

Also check if there are other active queries which might block the update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this SQL and see what is running:

```
SELECT TOP 20
        R.session_id, R.status, R.start_time, R.command, Q.text
FROM
        sys.dm_exec_requests R
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(R.sql_handle) Q
WHERE R.status in ('runnable')
ORDER BY R.start_time
```

More details:
[List the queries running on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941763/list-the-queries-running-on-sql-server)
or
http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/scripts/tsql/list-long-running-queries

Once I found someone shrinking database and blocking all other people.

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not your UPDATE is not doing anything, is just waiting, blocked by some other statement. Use [Activity Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to investigate what is causing the blocking. Most likely you have another statement that started a transaction and you forgot to close it.

There could be other causes too, eg.  database/log growth. Only you can do the investigation. An index on `CustomerNo` is required, true, but lack of an index is unlikely to explain 5 minutes on 370k records. Blocking is more likely.

There are more advanced tools out there like [`sp_whoisactive`](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/).

Answer (score 0):

5mn is way too long for 370k rows, even without any indexes, someone else is locking your update. use `sp_who2` (or activity monitor) and check for BlockedBy Column to find who is locking your update

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to rebuild your indexes. This should surely help you.

If you do not have index on CustomerNo field you must add one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a process that was blocking the update;
Run: 'EXEC sp_who;'
Find the process that is blocked by inspecting the 'blk' column; Let's say that we find a process that is blocked by '73';
Inspect the record with column 'spid' = '73' and if it's not important, run 'kill 73';

Answer (score -1):

370k records is nothing for sql erver. You should check indexes on this table. Each index makes update operation longer.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "Each index makes update operation longer"; In this case an index on the field being used in the `WHERE` clause would greatly speed up the update. If you have many indexes to update because of the fields which have changed, that _might_ slow down an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` but not much, and only when bulk loading many rows.